# Why boxed primitives doesn't support all operators?

Tags: java, autoboxing

After watching the Effective Java video I noticed that boxed primitives types support only four of the six comparison operators which `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=` and don't support `==` and `!=`.

My question is why boxed primitives don't support all operators?

Comment: Boxed primitives == ordinary objects, they aren't primitives any more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They do support `==` and `!=`. They just don't do what you're expecting.

For references, `==` and `!=` tell you whether two references are equal - that is, whether they refer to the same object.

```
class Thingy {}
Thingy a = new Thingy();
Thingy b = new Thingy();
System.out.println(a == b); // prints false, because a and b refer to different objects

Thingy c = b;
System.out.println(b == c); // prints true, because b and c refer to the same object
```

This applies to *all* reference types, including boxed primitives:

```
Integer a = new Integer(50);
Integer b = new Integer(50);
System.out.println(a == b); // prints false, because a and b refer to different objects

Integer c = b;
System.out.println(b == c); // prints true, because b and c refer to the same object
```

Now, references don't support `<` or `>` or `<=` or `>=`:

```
Thingy a = new Thingy();
Thingy b = new Thingy();
System.out.println(a < b); // compile error
```

however, boxed primitives can be auto-unboxed, and the unboxed primitives do support them, so the compiler uses auto-unboxing:

```
Integer a = new Integer(42);
Integer a = new Integer(43);

System.out.println(a < b);
// is automatically converted to
System.out.println(a.intValue() < b.intValue());
```

This auto-unboxing doesn't happen with `==` or `!=`, because those operators are already valid without auto-unboxing - they just don't do what you expect.

Answer (score 2):

Because in java the `==` and `!=` operators always do comparison of objects by reference, and boxed types are objects.